# cakephp 3 - trigger controller action with event

Tags: cakephp, events, cakephp-3.0, event-listener

I have the model `SlsInvoices` that triggers the event `SlsDispatches.send`.
Then inside my `SlsInvoicesController` I have an action called `emit`.

I need to trigger the `emit` action upon the `SlsDispatches.send` event.

The `SlsInvoices` model triggers the event as :

```
$event = new Event('SlsDispatches.send', $this, [ 'dispatchId' => $dispatchId ] );

$this->eventManager()->dispatch( $event );
```

But I cannot manage to register a listener to make the `emit` action trigger.
I've tried using :

```
$this->eventManager()->on( 'SlsDispatches.send', $this->processSentDispatch() );
```

where `$this->processSentDispatch()` is an action that further calls to `emit`.

Also I've tried implementing the listener interface inside de controller using :

```
public function implementedEvents()
{
    return [
        'SlsDispatches.send => 'processSentDispatch',
    ];
}
```

But the action is not triggered.

Is it possible to do what I want ? What am I missing ?

Thanks.
Regards.
Facundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance level event managers, ie `$this->eventManager()`, do not listen to events of other instance level event managers. If you want to listen to a locally dispatched event from outside of the object that holds the event manager instance, then you need to either subscribe to it via the objects event manager:

```
$SlsInvoicesObject->eventManager()
```

or via the global one:

```
\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()
```

Also you cannot pass a callback the way you are showing it, what you are doing there is calling the method, and passing its return value to the `on()` method.

Long story short, you would need to do something along the lines of:

```
$SlsInvoicesObject->eventManager()->on(
    'SlsDispatches.send',
    [$this, 'processSentDispatch']
);
```

or

```
\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(
    'SlsDispatches.send',
    [$this, 'processSentDispatch']
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Events System > Global Event Manager](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#global-event-manager)**
- **[PHP Manual > PHP Manual Language Reference Types > Callbacks / Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Will try it.